# Calculating Critical Value for Mixture of Two Chi-Square Distributions

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, p-value, chi-squared-test, mixture-distribution

Let's say I have a statistic X which is distributed as a mixture of two chi-square distributions; $$X \sim 0.5\chi^2_1 + 0.5\chi^2_2.$$
I'm wondering how I can calculate the critical value(and p-value) for this statistic $X$ at a given significance level $\alpha$?

Comment: If the dfs of your two $\chi^2$ differ by 1, you could use [`emdbook::dchibarsq()`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/emdbook/html/dchibarsq.html). Related, but no answer: [Mixture of two chi-squared distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/462593/1352)

Comment: The p-value is easy, but the critical value has to be computed using numerical methods.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/411671/919 or https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/496147/919 for the details and working general-purpose code.

Comment: @whuber Which method would you recommend to use to find the p-value?

Comment: The methods advocated in my posts on the subject: namely, use a well-crafted univariate root finder.